# SQL to copy missing data from one table to another

Tags: sql

I have two `SQL` tables with identical structures. The first column is a unique index named 'opt', the second column is named 'val'.

In table1 is populated with default values, eg:

```
 opt    val
 path  /tmp
 file  myfile.txt
 day   tuesday
 time  11:00
```

The second table, table2 will contain the same rows, but some of the val column values might be missing, eg:

```
 opt    val
 path  /var/tmp
 file  
 day   
 time  16:30
```

I'd like to go through each row in table2 and say 'is there a value in the val column? if not, get the val from table1 and update table2, so table 2 would end up as:

```
 opt    val
 path  /var/tmp
 file  myfile.txt
 day   tuesday
 time  16:30
```

ie fill in the missing data from table1.

I'm looking for a purely `SQL` way of doing this (ie without using `PHP`, `ASP` etc).

I'm kinda familiar with the `IF/ELSE` syntax in `SQL`, but I'm not sure how I iterate through each row in the table. Can anyone get me started in the right direction please?

Comment: The answer depends on your DB type. I guess that in most DBs (postgresql, mysql...) you need to write a procedure that read analyze and write the diff.

Comment: some versions of SQL use a concept called 'MERGE' which can update or insert as needed; alternately some support a 'MINUS' or 'EXCEPT' which can be used to identify the missing values easily and from which you could preform the update.  So what RDBMS is this?  And what SQL have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to run an update similar to the ones below:

**SQL Server:**

```
UPDATE T2
SET T2.val = T1.val
    , T2.opt = T1.opt
FROM Table2 T2 
    LEFT JOIN Table1 T1
        ON T2.opt = T1.opt
            OR T2.val = T1.val
WHERE T2.opt IS NULL
    OR T2.val IS NULL
```

**MySQL:**

```
UPDATE Table2 T2
  JOIN Table1 T1 ON T2.opt = T1.opt
    OR T2.val = T1.val
SET T2.val = T1.val
  , T2.opt = T1.opt
WHERE T2.VAL IS NULL
  OR T2.OPT IS NULL;
```

Take a look at below SQLFiddles to understand what this does to your data.

Issuing a variant of the above query to see what are the `NULL` values in your `table2`. Look [**here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48eefe/1).

In order to update these values, just run the `UPDATE` query above to modify the data in the table.

Take a look at [**this SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e763) to see what the results of the `UPDATE` will be. It is one of the variants presented above and will return the modified data from `table2`.

Answer (score 1):

An `sql cursor` is what you are looking for . You can check some online tutorials for future needs , but here is an example.

```
DECLARE
   c_opt table2.opt%type; //variable to be used for selecting into 
   c_name table2.val%type; // variable to be used for selecting into 
   CURSOR c_table2 is     // the actual cursor 
      SELECT opt,val FROM table2;
BEGIN
   OPEN c_customers;
   LOOP
      FETCH c_table2 into c_opt, c_val ;
      EXIT WHEN c_customers%notfound;
      IF (c_val is null) THEN UPDATE table 2 set val = (Select val from table 1 where opt = c_opt);
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE c_customers;
END;
```

Let us know if it worked , best regards.

Comment: I wouldn't try the [**`RBAR`**](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/) approach